# add delete button along with events in jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am generating events on fullCalendar with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                <?php 
                if(!empty($actionsa)){
                    foreach($actionsa as $actionind){ 
                        $animal = action_getanimal($actionind['animal_id']); 
                        if(!empty($animal)) $naitanim = "Animal (NAIT ID : ".$animal['nait_visual'].") ";  
                        else $naitanim = ""; echo "{ title: '".$naitanim.$actionind['notification']."', 

                        start: new Date(".date("Y,m-1,d", strtotime($actionind['due_date']))."),
                         url: '".SITE_ADDRESS.BASE_FOLDER."animals/id/".$actionind['animal_id']."'},";}}                
                ?>              
                ]
        });

    });
```

This works fine for data display. When I click on the event a new page is loaded, which contains other details of this event.

Now I need to add a delete button along with this event to delete this event and on clicking this button, it will show a popup box with a confirmation message.

can anyone help me???     thank you in advance....

Comment: Have you checked the `eventRender` callback? You can alter the structure of the event element before it gets rendered on the calendar.